# Build failed asp.net core 5.0 in vs 2017 build server

Tags: asp.net-core, build

I'm struggling with this. In my company  there is a build server that takes my code and try to compile it, but get the following errors:

```
error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
```

And the command to build is:

```
cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Msbuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release,OutputPath=E:\Jenkins-qua\workspace\XXXXXX-ADM365_IC\Release /t:Rebuild XXXXXX-adm365.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from E:\Jenkins-qua\workspace\WSGVCLAU-ADM365_IC
```

So it seems a problem with **visual studio 2017** not supporting *.net core 5.0*

So any way of fixing this? Ask the guys responsible of the server installing Vs tools 2019?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Use vs2019 cmd prompt if you can. Reinstall sdk. Ensure that .dll is pointed to. These are some fast answers that I can think of.